# Adding to the back of linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a function which takes in a struct, then adds that struct to the back of a linked List. I have figured out how to add to the front, but i cannot wrap my head around adding to the back.

This is my add to front function:

```
MusicRec * addToFront(MusicRec * theList, MusicRec * toBeAdded)
{
toBeAdded->next = theList;
theList = toBeAdded;
return(theList);
}
```

I am assuming that adding to the back of the list is quite similar this adding to the front, I just cannot seem to get the logic down

Comment: No, it's not quite similar. You'd have to travel by the linked list until you hit its tail - unless you have double-linked list, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Your code assumes that `theList` is not null on entry into the function. Is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to traverse the list to the end first, then add the new link, something like this:

```
MusicRec *addToBack(MusicRec *theList, MusicRec *toBeAdded)
{
    MusicRec *ptr = theList;
    if (!ptr) return toBeAdded;
    while (ptr->next)
        ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = toBeAdded;
    return theList;
}
```

Comment: Forgot when the list is empty :P `if (!theList) return toBeAdded;` That's a segfault waiting to happen!

Comment: I need to return a pointer to the head of the list. In this case would ptr be the pointer to the head of the list? I changed the code and added the "if(!theList) return toBeAdded;" is that what you meant?

Comment: Nope that too, just 'return theList;' instead of ptr. Added an edit to his post, but needs to be reviewed

Comment: Nope, no need, he asked for the "new" head, you return toBeAdded when theList is null

Answer (score 1):

Some recursive approaches:

Naive, O(n) stack memory:

```
node *add_tail(node *list, node *added)
{
   if (list == NULL)
     return added;
   list->next = add_tail(list->next, added);
   return list;
}
```

Wrapper plus tail recursive function (optimizable to loop):

```
void add_tail_rec(node **list, node *add)
{
   if (*list == NULL)
     *list = add;
   else
     add_tail_rec(&(*list)->next, add);
}

node *add_tail(node *list, node *add)
{
   add_tail_rec(&list, add);
   return list;
}
```

With fake head node instead of pointer-to-pointer:

```
void add_tail_rec(node *list, node *add)
{
   if (list->next == NULL)
     list->next = add;
   else
     add_tail_rec(list->next, add);
}

node *add_tail(node *list, node *add)
{
   node fake;
   fake.next = list;
   add_tail_rec(&fake, add);
   return fake.next;
}
```

Without fake head node or pointer-to-pointer, but copy of null test hoisted into wrapper:

```
void add_tail_rec(node *list, node *add)
{
   if (list->next == NULL)
     list->next = add;
   else
     add_tail_rec(list->next, add);
}

node *add_tail(node *list, node *add)
{
   if (list == NULL)
      return add;
   add_tail_rec(list, add);
   return list;
}
```

With extra context parameter in recursive function tracking insert location. With this trick, the recursive part returns a value: and that value is always just `list`! The wrapper can just use a ternary expression to either return `add` or `list` (with the item added).

```
node *add_tail_rec(node *list, node *add, node *where)
{
   return where->next == NULL 
          ? (where->next = add, list) 
          : add_tail_rec(list, add, where->next);
}

node *add_tail(node *list, node *add)
{
   return list == NULL ? add : add_tail_rec(list, add, list);
}
```

Comment: Lol totally not optimal, but really short, I like it.